# iOS MVC design pattern best practice in large project

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

First of all, I know what MVC is, theoretically.
I'm developing an app (let pretent that it's a large one), it has many `Model`, `View`, `Controller` classes and they're all seperated into different files (look good, right ?)

However, I feel like I'm abusing `Singleton design pattern`. 
I'm writing my code in this way:

- `Model classes` only have properties.
- A `Database's singleton` is created to manipulate whatever in the database. For example, I've 10 `Model` classes, so I've to write 30 methods in this `singleton` to select, update, delete data. (this is where I feel so wrong).
- `Controllers` import `Models` and call methods in `Database's singleton`.

Am I doing it wrong ? I remembered when I began to code with `Java`, I used to create `bussiness object` and `data access object` for each `Model`.

Should I follow that or what's the best practice in this case ? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at some of the sample app's Apple has made available;
It's also a matter of what makes sense as a developer;
I don't think I would create a series of classes that only have properties, but I guess there might be a case where that would make sense;
anyway here's [a link] https://developer.apple.com/resources/
search for sample code you may have to log in as a developer